# Matching documents to keywords

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like the following:

This is a maintenance log and the text describes the work done and the rest of the columns are components. Each entry is a separate maintenance item and this is a data frame.

```
Text                                       Engine Coolant Brakes Battery
Engine Oil changed and battery replaced.    0      0       0      0
Coolant changed.                             0      0       0     0
```

I am looking to transform it such that I get a data frame like the one below:

```
Text                                       Engine Coolant Brakes Battery
Engine Oil changed and battery replaced.    1       0       0      1
Coolant changed.                             0      1       0     0
```

So basically I am looking to match the parts serviced and note them for each maintenance item.
I tried an ifelse() on it, but was not successful.
I only got a long string of zeroes.
Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `grepl` for this

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("Engine Oil changed and battery replaced.", "Coolant changed."))

df$Engine <- grepl("Engine", df$text, ignore.case = TRUE)*1
df$Coolant <- grepl("Coolant", df$text, ignore.case = TRUE)*1 
df$Brakes <- grepl("Brakes", df$text, ignore.case = TRUE)*1 
df$Battery <- as.numeric(grepl("Engine", df$text, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Note, that `grepl` returns TRUE or FALSE. `*1` turns it into numeric. I used `as.numeric` for Battery to demonstrate this. If "battery" occurs two times it would still return 1 for TRUE.